# Estou com problema em criar um método public async Task<ActionResult> Método de ação síncrona C# Web API

Tags: c#, .net, api

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou com esse problema para criar um método na API não reconhece o ActionResult

[image: Erro]

Comment: já tentou colocar no using System.Web.Mvc; ?

Comment: aproveitando a dica do @LucianoAzevedo quando acontece isso, coloque o cursor no nome da classe e tecle CTRL+.  (ponto) e o VS irá te sugerir a namespace que falta referenciar (se não aparecer pode estar faltando incluir a referência do assembly no projeto ou o nome da classe pode estar errado)

Comment: Coloquei o using System.Web.Mvc também  nao funciona e no CTRL+. (ponto) nao segue nada alem de tornar o método síncrono

Comment: Qual seria a referencia do assembly que devo adicionar @JMSlasher

Comment: estranho estar faltando neste caso, principalmente se vc criou o projeto a partir do template de aplicação asp.net mvc... tenta ir no gerenciador de pacotes nuget e busque por Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc se aparecer opção para instalar, instale

Comment: Já tentou referenciar a "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" ?